# Too Many Arguments to 'Public sub New() VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I have this problem (**Too Many Arguments to 'Public sub New()** 
) with this little shared Sub, i wanna create a smart notification window, that i call form another forms. All is good, but when i tryed to write this Sub for calling another Form with custom properties, comes this error...

My code:

```
Public Sub Tray_ért(ByVal típus As Típus, ByVal cím As String, ByVal szöveg As String)
    lbl_főcím.Text = cím
    lbl_szöveg.Text = szöveg
    Select Case típus
        Case Típus.Információ
            Me.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue
            pb_ikon.Image = Ikonok.Images.Item(1)
        Case Típus.Sikeres
            Me.BackColor = Color.SeaGreen
            pb_ikon.Image = Ikonok.Images.Item(3)
        Case Típus.Figyelmeztetés
            Me.BackColor = Color.Khaki
            pb_ikon.Image = Ikonok.Images.Item(4)
        Case Típus.Hiba
            Me.BackColor = Color.Red
            pb_ikon.Image = Ikonok.Images.Item(0)
        Case Típus.Vizsgálat
            Me.BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue
            pb_ikon.Image = Ikonok.Images.Item(2)
    End Select
End Sub
Public Enum Típus
    Információ
    Sikeres
    Figyelmeztetés
    Hiba
    Vizsgálat
End Enum 
Public Shared Sub Show(ByVal típus As Típus, ByVal cím As String, ByVal szöveg As String)

        Dim értesítés As New LenSoft_Blay_Anti_Malware.Értesítés_tray_ablak
        értesítés = New Értesítés_tray_ablak(típus, cím, szöveg) 'here become i this error for the value tray_ért!

    End Sub
```

So i definied soon the "Típus As Enum", i dont know whats here wrong. Only, the típus (As Típus) is underlined.

So can someone help me??
Thanks to all!

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `Sub New` in `Class Értesítés_tray_ablak`?

Comment: What is `Értesítés_tray_ablak`?  How many arguments does its constructor expect?  The error seems to indicate that it expects fewer than three.

Comment: I solvad my problem! Thanks for all!